# Instant Search on Magento

Tags: magento2, cache

I am trying to **speed up** the **Magento search** and load results over **ajax**.

I have made a completely ajax search and it works however is slow in Magento 2. In Magento 1 i managed to make it near instant like below sites but this was on a site with few products.

I am seeing a few stores with 1000s of products starting to pop up recently with an incredibly fast search and its making me jealous:

https://gmsuppliesltd.co.uk

https://www.allianceonline.co.uk/

I know gm is Magento 1 and not sure on Alliance but was wondering if there are any modules that can allow for Magento 2 search to be as fast as this and how are they doing this?

Comment: thy are using https://www.algolia.com/ search for getting search data and then it will render data from website and then create HTML and display result

Comment: Ah yeah that is what gmsupplies is using. Interesting.

Comment: The default Magento 2 plugin i would want to be full screen and replace the search rather than like a mini search tho. Maybe I could mod it to but the filters may end up being a pain.